# Why is SQL Server casting GETDATE() to an other value than CAST('yyyy-mm-dd')?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm working with SQL Server for many years and I think I have a really strange thing here.

When I execute these 2 queries:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2017-03-28' AS DATETIME) AS INT)

SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS INT), GETDATE()
```

I get these outputs:

```
42820
42821   2017-03-28 20:49:10.360
```

So I'm totally clueless about this; how can 28 march 2017 be cast to 42820 and 28 march 2017 20:49 to 42821?

To make it a little more strange, I've figured out that the point for going 1 higher is 12:00 am. I'm really lost...

Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: @marc_s `datetime` is convertible to `float`, where the integer part represents the date, and the fractional part represents the time. Converting to `int` gets rid of the fractional part, so it's not as obvious as your comment suggests.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what @marc_s said. It's just that datetimes (as integers) start at midday. e.g. 0 is anything before 1900-01-01 11:59:59.997 and 1 begins at 1900-01-01 12:00:00.000. As for why, I couldn't tell you. It's just how it was implemented.

Comment: Actually my previous comment was wrong. I ran a couple tests and it flips over to 1 at 1900-01-01 11:59:59.995. I'm not 100% sure why, but when converting a datetime to an integer, it appears to round up the `REAL` value. Try the following to see what I mean: `DECLARE @D1 DATETIME = '1900-01-01 11:59:59.995', @D2 DATETIME = '1900-01-01 11:59:59.994'; SELECT CAST(@D1 AS INT), CAST(@D1 AS REAL), CAST(@D2 AS INT), CAST(@D2 AS REAL);` (Note: The `REAL` values differ from the `FLOAT` values for these).

Comment: If you want to test properly, cast to `float`, not `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an interesting feature... You can get around it by casting to float first though.

```
select cast(cast('20170328' as datetime) as int)

select convert(int,convert(float,getdate()))
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YVXUJ72002

Both return `42820`

Answer (score 0):

casting datetime is rounded from 12:00:00

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2017-03-28 12:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS INT)
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS INT), GETDATE()


SELECT CAST(CAST('2017-03-28 11:59:59' AS DATETIME) AS INT)
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS INT), GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rounding to one day：

```
--00:00:00~12:00:00
SELECT CAST(CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS INT) 
--12:00:00~24:00:00
SELECT CAST(CAST('1900-01-01 12:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS INT) 

--00:00:00.000~11:59:59.994
SELECT CAST(CAST('1900-01-01 11:59:59.994' AS DATETIME) AS INT) 
--11:59:59.995~23:59:59.999
SELECT CAST(CAST('1900-01-01 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It's clear how it works. But it's completely new to me.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It shouldn't be posted as one. You may want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) from the help section.